# Why can't I install pycairo on windows 10

Tags: python, pycairo

This is the error log:

```
Running setup.py install for pycairo ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ANASIM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1lo1lxwq\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ANASIM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1lo1lxwq\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANASIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x0p9yla8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\anaconda3\Include\pycairo'
     cwd: C:\Users\ANASIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1lo1lxwq\pycairo\
Complete output (18 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\cairo
copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\cairo
copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\cairo
copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\cairo
running build_ext
building 'cairo._cairo' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\cairo
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=19 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -Ic:\anaconda3\include -Ic:\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\cairo/device.obj
device.c
c:\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\ANASIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1lo1lxwq\pycairo\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ANASIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1lo1lxwq\pycairo\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANASIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x0p9yla8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\anaconda3\Include\pycairo' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: What was the installation command?

Comment: pip3 install pycairo

Comment: If you're using an Anaconda environment, you should probably use `conda install`.